# Does GTA V Online Network Merge Xbox 360 and PS3 players?

Tags: xbox-360, ps3, grand-theft-auto-online

Can GTA V  Online Network Merge Xbox 360 and PS3 players, or is it two individual networks? (Can crews cross platform)

Comment: Can't say for sure but I'm 99% sure it doesn't, it's against Xbox policy for games to talk to non-Xbox Live servers.

Comment: Im gonna have to agree with Ben. Generally games stick to their own platform when doing online, but recently cross platform games have been slowly emerging. I would expect GTA 5 to not use cross platform, though, because xbox live and PSN are 2 very different platforms in how they are set up from a technical point.

Comment: It's happened in the past - remember Quake3 on Dreamcast

Comment: I think it may actually be one homogeneous network, because the character profiles are stored on Rockstar Social's cloud. Do not forget that MMO games like Final Fantasy XI are on PC, PS2, PS3 and Xbox 360 through the proprietary PlayOnline network.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman FFXI is sort of an extreme outlier from several years ago, though, which predates Microsoft's more strict stance on that sort of thing; MS has flatly refused more recent games the opportunity for cross-platform play due to their own policies.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman did FFXI feature cross-platform play? I'm almost certain it didn't.

Comment: @TZHX: Yes, it does. It has a single set of servers for each and every platform. It was a very unique experience back in the day, I had a single account and was able to play the game on my PS2 and PC. The PS2 had a very clunky input scheme, needless to say, but it was the same exact servers - in fact, you play on the same servers as the Japanese crowd so they have a pre-defined phrases that are translated across languages.

Comment: Hmm. I was fairly sure the xbox version at least was isolated. I know it needed a different account than the PC version (ie two subscription fees).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, there is not cross-platform play in GTA 5.

Comment: What about if you have a level 25 character on PS3? Provided that it has not been deleted already by the "cloud", will I be able to play with it on PC?

Comment: GTA5 is not available on PC, so no.

Comment: Hence why I used the future tense...

Comment: @mastergalen Considering the fact that *GTA 5 PC* has not yet been released, there is no way we can answer that particular question for certain. If you insist on asking, the question would almost definitely be closed as off-topic until the PC version's release.

Comment: Based on the lack of connection between Xbox and ps3 it seems unlikely that PC will be inter operable with the console versions, if a PC version ever materialises.

Comment: @TZHX I wouldn't use that as an arguement. Portal 2 is an example of a cross-platform between PS3 and PC. Is it possible? yes... Will it happen? maybe if steam or someone else steps up their game.

Comment: It's possible. But unlikely. Portal 2 was a Valve game, so they had some interest in making extra effort. Rockstar haven't even **announced** a PC version of the game, so until they do (if they do) and it has been released, we don't know what will happen. I said "it seems unlikely", not "it absolutely won't happen", btw.